# Extract data table from a specific page with multiple same name tables using Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am very new to python and BeautifulSoup. I wrote the code below to call up the website: https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB-standings.shtml, with the goal of scraping the table at the bottom named "MLB Detailed Standings" and exporting to a CSV file. My code successfully creates a CSV file but with the wrong data table pulled and it is missing the first column with the team names. My code pulls in the "East Division" table up top (excluding the first column) rather than my targeted table with the full "MLB Detailed Standings" table at the bottom.

Wondering if there is a simple way to pull the MLB Detailed Standings table at the bottom. When I inspect the page, the ID for the specific table I am trying to pull is: "expanded_standings_overall". Do I need to reference this in my code? Or, any other guidance to rework the code to pull the correct table would be greatly appreciated. Again, I very new and trying my best to learn.

```
import requests
import csv
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# static urls
season = datetime.datetime.now().year
URL = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB-standings.shtml".format(season=season)

# request the data
batting_html = requests.get(URL).text

def parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(input_html, out_file_name):
    """
    Take a HTML stats page from fangraphs and parse it out to a CSV file.
    """
    # parse input
    soup = BeautifulSoup(input_html, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", class_=["sortable,", "stats_table", "now_sortable"])

    # get headers
    headers_html = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
    headers = []
    for header in headers_html:
        headers.append(header.text)
    print(headers)

    # get rows
    rows = []
    rows_html = table.find_all("tr")
    for row in rows_html:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all("td"):
            row_data.append(cell.text)
        rows.append(row_data)

    # write to CSV file
    with open(out_file_name, "w") as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerows(rows)

parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(batting_html, 'BBRefTest.csv')
```

Comment: The answer to the request contains only 6 tables. It looks like you need to play with header and/or session to obtain a full answer.

Comment: Just an FYI, there is a fairly popular Python library that can be used to scrape baseball-reference.com https://github.com/jldbc/pybaseball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, yes, it would be better to reference the ID as you would suspect the developer has made this ID unique to this table vs class which are just style descriptor.

Now, the problem run deeper. A quick look at the page code actually shows that the html that defines the table is commented out a few tags above. I suspect a script 'enables' this code on the client-side (in your browser). *requests.get* which just pull out the html without processing any javascript doesn't catch it (you could check the content of *batting_html* to verify that).

A very quick and dirty fix would be to catch the commented out code and reprocess it in BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import Comment
...

# parse input
soup = BeautifulSoup(input_html, "lxml")
dynamic_content = soup.find("div", id="all_expanded_standings_overall")
comments = dynamic_content.find(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
table = BeautifulSoup(comments, "lxml")

# get headers
```

By the way, you want to specify utf8 encoding when writing your file ...

```
with open(out_file_name, "w", encoding="utf8") as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    ...
```

Now that's really 'quick and dirty' and I would try to check deeper into the html code and javascript what is really happening before scaling this out to other pages.